# Prism and IEventAggregator: Trouble at loading Modules

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef, bootstrapper

I'm actually working on a project using WPF, MEF and Prism. When I start the application, I need to export a module from the container to open a configuration window before the mainwindow is shown. The code therefore is like this:

```
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {       base.OnStartup(e);
                Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
                bootstrapper.Run();

                var window = bootstrapper.statcontainer.GetExport<Configshell>();
                var configview = bootstrapper.statcontainer.GetExport<Module.Module1.View.ConfigView>();
                window.Value.Show();
                Keyboard.Focus(configview.Value.ok_button); }
```

Where bootstrapper.statcontainer is a public CompositeContainer (allocated with the "Maincontainer" of the MEFBootstrapper in CreateContainer-Method). I use it to export modules at startup.
Now at GetExport() I get the following first chance exception thrown:

> GetExportedValue cannot be called before prerequisite import 'MyApp.Module.Module2.ViewModels.Module2_Functions..ctor (Parameter="C_Aggregator", ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.PubSubEvents.IEventAggregator")' has been set.

And this is how the ctor there looks like:

```
    [Import]
    public IEventAggregator Configaggregator;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Module2_Functions(IEventAggregator C_Aggregator)
    {
        this.Configaggregator = C_Aggregator;
        Configaggregator.GetEvent<FromConfigWindow>();
        FromConfigWindow.Instance.Subscribe(receiveStatusFromConfigWindow);
        Configaggregator.GetEvent<ToConfigWindow>();
    }
```

I'am using the EventAggregator to publish the configuration and have the same ctor in another module. The confusing thing is that it worked that way until I added another completely independent import to that ViewModel. Here is how the ctor of the ConfigwindowViewModel looks like:

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ConfigVM(IEventAggregator C_aggregator)
    {
        this.Configaggregator = C_aggregator;
        Configaggregator.GetEvent<ToConfigWindow>();
        ToConfigWindow.Instance.Subscribe(actualizeCompStatus);
        Configaggregator.GetEvent<FromConfigWindow>();
    }

    [Import]
    public IEventAggregator Configaggregator;
```

The two events are looking like this and both already worked until 2 days ago ;-)

```
[Export]
public class FromConfigWindow : PubSubEvent<Int16> 
{
    private static readonly EventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private static readonly FromConfigWindow _event;

    static FromConfigWindow()
    {
        _eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
        _event = _eventAggregator.GetEvent<FromConfigWindow>();
    }

    public static FromConfigWindow Instance
    {
        get { return _event; }
    }
}
[Export]
public class ToConfigWindow : PubSubEvent<Int16>
{
    private static readonly EventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private static readonly ToConfigWindow _event;

    static ToConfigWindow()
    {
        _eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
        _event = _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ToConfigWindow>();
    }

    public static ToConfigWindow Instance
    {
        get { return _event; }
    }
}
```

So finally the Problem looks to me like the EventAggregator doesn't get instanciated and therefore the exception gets thrown. But how can I work around this? Or am I doing something wrong in the linkage of the Aggregator in the constructors?

I already tried to modify all constructor arguments with an [Import] attribute, this threw the same exception as well, or removing all [Import] attributes form the IEventAggregator Configaggregator objects in the ViewModels.

The problem is similar to [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309467/getexportedvalue-cannot-be-called-before-prerequisite-import-has-been-set) but in my case happens with the EventAggregator from the Prism framework.

Please tell me if I should provide you more parts of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're Exporting your `PubSubEvents` or holding a reference to a static new `EventAggregator` in them. You should only be using one instance of `EventAggregator` (in this example) which you'll get from your container (Prism will put it there for you).

You should go back to basics and read the excellent [Prism documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.40).aspx). Section 9 "Communicating Between Loosely Coupled Components" for an overview of EventAggregator and PubSubEvents.

If you want to create a bare bones project which simulates the problem you're having and upload it somewhere, I'll gladly have a look at it for you.

Comment: Since I'm new to Prism, that has been something I tried to make like some guys [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/591221/Simple-EventAggregator-in-WPF-PRISM) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample) but you are right, I just tested it and there is no need for some additional code in the event-class itself. I also get the EventAggregator now by using the ServiceLocator, which works great: `public IEventAggregator Configaggregator = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>()`; Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are you getting the EventAggregator from the container directly rather than importing it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is because you have not satisfied all your imports before beginning operations on them.  I concur with ChrisO, you should go back and check out the docs.  There are a lot of things going on here which seem to be overcomplicating things.  Why is there a `new EventAggregator()` in there?  MEF should import that dependency for you.  Why all the messing around with the container and getting exports?  It seems you are doing a lot of work that should be taken care of by MEF and Prism.

Comment: Yes since that's my first software project and I'm new to Prism, I realize a lot of things all the time which I made overcomplicated ;-) You're right, the Container is better accessable through the ServiceLocator approach which I found now:`var container = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(CompositionContainer);` I haven't tested this so far, just found it [here](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/263641) by Miguel Bronzovic's post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure.  But what I'm really wondering is why do you need the container at all?  It's job is just to inject instances of the things you need where you need them.  If you are trying to get a specific instance from the container, check out the MEF ExportFactory  https://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PartCreator rather than getting the container.  I've written about 50 MEF based apps, and have never needed access directly to the container beyond composition time.

Comment: Yes, but I made this as a workaround since I needed to get an Import injected in the App-Class. And my Imports have always been "null" there after the bootstrapper finished (although the executingAssembly got placed in the AggregateCatalog) and an exception showed up. So I decided to access the Container directly which worked then. Another possibility would have been to toggle the application's mainwindow with the configuration-window but I didn't like that approach since it crashes the structure of the architecture.